# Undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, capistrano

I am trying to get Capistrano up and running for the first time in a rails app. I have a linux server running Ubuntu 12.04, nginx, unicorn and rails, however, I seem to be running into a few issues. I am also using Capistrano 3.0.0, rails 3.2.14, bundler 1.4.0 & ruby 1.9.3p448 using RVM.

I only have a production stage set up and at this point in time and I'm only concerned with Capistrano communicating with my server and pushing my code from github ( No migrations and bundling etc just yet).

When I try the command `cap production deploy:check` or  `cap production deploy:setup` ( which seems to be deprecated?) with the setup below, I get the following error msg:

I'm not really sure where to start on this error, and google doesn't suggest much. I have tried adding the `rvm-capistrano` gem but to no avail. How can I amend my code to address this error?

```
    cap aborted!
undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.4.0.rc.1/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `load'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"

set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "production"

set :application, "my_app"
set :user, "andrew"
set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "https://github.com/my_repo/#{application}"
set :branch, "master"

set :deploy_to, "/home/rails/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  task :restart, roles: :app do
      run "touch #{current_path}tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
```

deploy/production.rb

```
#Real IP ommitted 
server "10.2.32.68", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
```

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
# require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**EDIT** After looking at the offending line in capistrano.rb within bundler it mentions to add require 'bundler/deployment' to deploy.rb, which has seemed to get rid of the capistrano instance error.

**NOTE** Downgraded to capistrano 2.15.5 which got rid of the errors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, there were a couple of changes made in capistrano 3.
See the release notes : **http://www.capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html**

Also go through the readme.
**https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md**

Capistrano 3 has moved out bundler integration into a gem.To solve your problem :

```
 1. Uncomment require 'capistrano/bundler' from capify. 
 2. add gem 'capistrano-bundler' to your gemfile.
 3. Go through the comments in capify file and uncomment whichever module you require.
```

**Oh and if you don't wanna use bundler as of yet, remove the first line : require "bundler/capistrano". easy as that.**

Also you can't use variables like the previous way now.Instead of directly reading it, use fetch(:application) to read a variable.

I would be easier for you to move back to capistrano v2.

Comment: I really don't think moving back to v2 is easier.  First it's worth trying to start over with a cap install (though make back ups of your deploy.rb,production.rb and capifile files first!), then add pieces back in until it works.  Also, I fixed this problem by using capistrano 3.1.  I the issue on capistrano 3.3.5.

Comment: @yekta the question was asked in 2013. Just when cap 3 was launched. At that point of time it would have been easier for him to move back to v2, since not much help was available.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this problem is because Bundler 1.3.5 is not compatible with the latest version of Capistrano. Try upgrading to the Bundler pre-releases: `gem install bundler --pre`.

---

I noticed also that you're using a very old version of Rails 3.2, which is probably vulnerable to some security exploits. I would really strongly recommend upgrading that version of Rails to something more recent, like Rails 3.2.14.

Comment: I think you are right, this has also highlighted a few issues in my project. Upgrading to 3.2.14 as suggested, will try to re-capify when fully updated and get back to this.

Comment: For what its worth upgrading did not resolve this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

For Capistrano 3, they recommend using `http://github.com/capistrano/bundler`

Its mentioned here `https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/capistrano.rb`