# Undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class on `cap deploy:setup`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

```
$ bundle exec cap deploy:setup
/Users/development/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit.rb:3: 
  warning: already initialized constant SSHKit::StandardError
/Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit.rb:3: 
  warning: previous definition of StandardError was here

cap aborted!
undefined method `instance' for Capistrano::Configuration:Class
/Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railsless-deploy-1.1.2/lib/railsless-deploy.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/development/Sites/singapore/Capfile:1:in `require'
/Users/development/Sites/singapore/Capfile:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:22:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/development/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/capistrano-3.0.0/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am fairly new to capistrano but have used it successfully in the past without this amount of problems. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19370386/undefined-method-instance-for-capistranoconfigurationclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am fairly new to capistrano but have used it successfully in the past without this amount of problems. Does anyone know a fix for this?

I guess you need to stay on Version 2, modify the line in your `Gemfile`, to read something like:

```
gem "capistrano", "~> 2.15.0"
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to get this working myself yesterday in the end. Implementing the same solution as the one you suggested. Therefore I am marking this as the answer. Tks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I got a similar error message, but the stacktrace was from the whenever gem.  The problem is that whenever 0.8.x does not work with capistrano 3.x, so I upgraded to whenever 0.9.0.  @lee-hambley, I suggest adding a mention at http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/ of the whenever upgrade.

Comment: Rather than downgrading to Capistrano 2, @IsaacBetesh's suggestion to upgrade the whenever gem worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I had to do a couple steps to get it to work. First uninstall all existing versions of Capistrano (**if you have multiple versions, remove all of them**)

```
sudo gem uninstall Capistrano
```

then add a `Gemfile` to your repo with the text given above

```
gem "capistrano", "~> 2.15.0"
```

make sure you have `bundle` installed

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

finally install

```
sudo bundle install
```